# How can I resolve a package installation error in Julia on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, julia

I have just started using Julia on a Windows 10 machine, and I have been trying to install some very basic packages. When I use the `Pkg.add()` command, however, the command window returns the following error:

```
ERROR: SystemError: opening file C:\Users\username\.julia\environments\v1.0\Project.toml: Permission denied
```

The error message pops up even when using the Administrator mode. Any advice or tips would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe take a look at this https://discourse.julialang.org/t/ijulia-install-issue/45037

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Following the advice at the bottom of the thread, deleting `.julia` and reinstalling packages solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Delete `.julia` folder or set a new location for the `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH`.
2. Once done use a non-administrator account (the one you normally work with) to reinstall packages.